# Python-Raspberry pi: get int from popen result

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, popen

I'm using python on raspberry py.
I'm trying to read values ​​from a i2c accelerometer using an external application (Hipi). 
To do this I used the Popen function in this way:

```
Xprev=Popen(['hipi-i2c', "r", "1", "0x1D", "0x01"])    # read X value
```

The result is a single value (for example `100`).
If I try to print the result from python or execute the same command from the command line it works.

I need to add this value to another to perform a comparison and see if the accelerometer is moving, but if I do a sum like

```
S=10              # Threshold
Xpt=Xprev + S     # Xprev from previous read
Xnt=Xprev - S     # Xprev from previous read
```

the result of sum is: `unsupported operand type (s) for +: 'Popen' and 'int'`

Comment: Xprev is an object of some sort. What you need to do is look in the object and figure out the name of the variable you are trying to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cmdline = ['hipi-i2c', 'r', '1', '0x1D', '0x01']
result = Popen(
    cmdline
    , stdin=PIPE
    , stdout=PIPE
    , stderr=PIPE
)
output = result.stdout.readlines()
try:
    X = int(output[0])
except:
    pass

print X
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
It works with your code using this to convert X (or "output") in a int var:   X=map(int, result.stdout.readlines())[0]